# Density of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $D_A(n) = \dfrac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n}$.  One says $A$ has **density** if $\lim_n D_A(n)$ exists and is finite.

I know there exist sets with and without density, and that finite sets have density, and the complement of sets with density have density.  $A$ has density if an only if $B$ has density whenever the "tail" of $A$ matches the "tail" of $B$.

*However my question has to do with whether the intersection of two sets with density must have density?*

If so, then we can say something about finite unions of sets with density (since the collection of sets with density are closed under complementation).

Answer (score 6):

No.  You could let $A$ be the set of odd numbers, and $B$ be those numbers that are even if they lie between $2^{2^{2k}}$ and $2^{2^{2k+1}}-1$, and odd if they lie between $2^{2^{2k+1}}$ and $2^{2^{2k+2}}-1$ for some $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots$.